# Working with child elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Why does this work?:

```
$(".inner").css("height", 10);
```

And this doesn't:

```
$(".outer").children().css("height", 10);
```

UPDATE:

Just to be clear, the above DOES work.  See answer below.

Comment: Are you sure the `.inner` elements are **direct** children?

Comment: Use Firebug to check out the HTML, you'll see the CSS is applied. The reason why you're not seeing the elements have that height is probably a different issue.

Comment: @Niels - None of those issues should make the 2 above statements behave differently though, at least not that I can imagine.

Comment: @Nick I'm not saying the statements behave differently. I *am* saying that @Moose Factory is probably not seeing the results in his browser, aka the .inner elements are not getting the height of 10px. *That* is probably another issue. However if he takes a look at the HTML using Firebug he'll see that the css attribute is applied to the elements.

Comment: @Niels - if that was the case though, both of the jQuery calls above would have the same (no) effect...but that isn't happening here :)

Comment: @Nick I just read the update and my suggested theory for why @MooseFactory did not see the elements change height has been dismissed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What you have works](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/LUqS6/), or rather what you *posted* works.

My best guess is that in your actual markup the `.inner` `<div>` elements aren't *direct* (immediate) children of `.outer`, but instead wrapped in something else.

In what you posted `$(".inner")` and `$(".outer").children()` give the exact same element set, and [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) operates on all elements in the set...so by all means the result should be identical.

Comment: Yes, well spotted.  I only gave you the essence of my problem.  There was indeed another level of <div> in the way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The two are equivalent and in fact [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/PURKd/).